# Iterating over all scenes before compilation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to iterate over all my game scenes with script and make some changes. I need this to be done before game compilation.

I've tried to google preprocess scripting in Unity. Did I understand correctly that I need to use something like BuildPipeline? Are there any simple examples to understand how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, finally I managed to do it myself. If someone will handle same problem, here is my code:

```
class MyBuilder : Editor {

    private static string[] FillLevels ()
    {
        return (from scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes where scene.enabled select scene.path).ToArray ();
    }

    [MenuItem ("MyTool/BuildGame")]
    public static void  buildGame()
    {
        string[] levels = FillLevels ();
        foreach (string level in levels) {
            EditorApplication.OpenScene (level);
            object[] allObjects = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll (typeof(UnityEngine.GameObject));
            foreach (object thisObject in allObjects) {
               /* my gameObjects changing before compilation */
            }
            EditorApplication.SaveScene ();
        }
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer (levels, Path.GetFullPath (Application.dataPath + "/../game.exe"), BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows, BuildOptions.None);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an [**Editor Script**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.html). With the API reference link you should be able to do what ever you want to the scene. The script below will allow you to save those changes.

This is an example of an Editor script that will allow you to save a change done to a scene, [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.SaveScene.html):

```
import UnityEditor;

class SimpleAutoSave extends EditorWindow 
{
    var saveTime : float = 300;
    var nextSave : float = 0;

    @MenuItem("Example/Simple autoSave")
    static function Init() 
    {
        var window : SimpleAutoSave = EditorWindow.GetWindowWithRect(SimpleAutoSave, Rect(0,0,165,40));
        window.Show();
    }

    function OnGUI() 
    {
         EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Save Each:", saveTime + " Secs");
         var timeToSave : int = nextSave - EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup;
         EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Next Save:", timeToSave.ToString() + " Sec");
         this.Repaint();

        if(EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup > nextSave) 
        {
            var path : String [] = EditorApplication.currentScene.Split(char.Parse("/"));
            path[path.Length -1] = "AutoSave_" + path[path.Length-1];   
            EditorApplication.SaveScene(String.Join("/",path), true);
            Debug.Log("Saved Scene");
            nextSave = EditorApplication.timeSinceStartup + saveTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am afraid, that is not exactly what I need. With this example I can save the **current** scene, but my big problem is (as I mentioned in question) that I need to iterate over **all** scenes in my game. And before compilation.